# Using IN operator, with CASE WHEN with GROUP BY expression SQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am getting "ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression" when trying to run following query

```
SELECT COUNT(column_1),
  CASE
    WHEN column_2 = 'Y'
    OR column_3  IN
      (SELECT column_4 FROM table_2
      )
    THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
  END
FROM table_1
GROUP BY
  CASE
    WHEN column_2 = 'Y'
    OR column_3  IN
      (SELECT column_4 FROM table_2
      )
    THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
  END
```

Product Used= Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition
Version = 11.1.0.7.0 (64-bit production)

Is there any syntax error, or anything which is wrong in query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine:

```
WITH table_1 AS (
  SELECT 'Y' column_1, 'N' column_2, 3 column_3 FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'N', 'Y', 3 FROM dual
), 
table_2 AS (
  SELECT 1 column_4 FROM dual
)
SELECT COUNT(column_1),
  CASE
    WHEN column_2 = 'Y'
    OR column_3  IN
      (SELECT column_4 FROM table_2
      )
    THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
  END
FROM table_1
GROUP BY
  CASE
    WHEN column_2 = 'Y'
    OR column_3  IN
      (SELECT column_4 FROM table_2
      )
    THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
  END;
```

But if I change this definition:

```
table_2 AS (
  SELECT 3 column_4 FROM dual
)
```

so the condition becomes true:

```
 OR column_3  IN
          (SELECT column_4 FROM table_2
          )
```

then I also get "ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression"

I think Oracle doesn't like a subquery in the GROUP BY. Oracle documentation states that you can't use subqueries in the GROUP BY, but it's allowed to use them in the CASE.

I suppose it will be difficult to find an official reference why it works like this. There are lots of such things with complicated queries in Oracle. Some of them are bugs, some are just undocumented features.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Oracle allows subqueries in the `group by` clause.  You can rewrite this query using a subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), col
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             (CASE WHEN column_2 = 'Y' OR
                        column_3  IN (SELECT column_4 FROM table_2)
                   THEN 'Y'
                   ELSE 'N'
              END) as col
      FROM table_1 t
     ) t
GROUP BY col;
```